# Ifelse temperature modelling

Tags: r

I am building a model in R and I have a data frame of daily temperature data in Kelvin (CSV file). I will run the model individually for each station. The literature I am basing the model off of states: when the `temperature` rises above `285.15`, spawning is induced and `ER` is reduced to `0`, meaning my graphical output should fall to zero and start climbing again after the temperature decreases. My question is this: How would I write this command into R? Thus far I have written:

```
spawn <- ER
spawning <- ifelse(Mussel_Daily_Temp$AS_TEMP > 285.15, ER-ER, 0)
```

I have also tried:

```
if(temperature > 285.15) {ER-ER}
```

My parameters look like this:

```
param <- list(Temperature = Mussel_Daily_Temp$AS_TEMP, etc....)
```

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: Please give some example data and the expected results.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/ORs3u the whole model uses cyclical water temperature data in Kelvin so once a year the water will elevate above 285.15 K -  enough to trigger a spawning event which would drain the 'ER' or effective reproduction reserve

Comment: I meant the data frame. Please paste the head of Mussel_Daily_Temp into the question and what you would like the data to look like after the code is run in there as well.

Answer (score 1):

you are on the right path:

```
ifelse(Mussel_Daily_Temp$AS_TEMP > 285.15, 'ER-ER', 0)
```

Comment: `Warning messages:
1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  display list redraw incomplete
2: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  invalid graphics state` It returned the follwing in the console....

Comment: try without the assignment `<-`

Comment: ER still doesn't change, unfortunately...no errors showing. this is what I have so far: `spawn <- ER
   ifelse(Mussel_Daily_Temp$AS_TEMP > 285.15, 'ER-ER', 0)`